# available sort by not editable

Tags: magento-1.9, checkbox, sort

We have a lot of module installed and lot of configuration done and just see that we are not able to add more category due to available product listing sort by not editable and the checkbox not clickable. Here is a picture of the error:

[image: Attribute "Available Product Listing Sort By" is required.]

As you can see we always have the error message: "Available Product Listing Sort By" is required.

When we use different language than all store views, the available product listing work good, does anybody have same problem before?

We use Magento 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.2.3

We also have the Default Product Listing Sort By not clickable on checkbox and / or editable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time we have found why, we have use code from this website http://www.codecollector.net/view/8A743305-8E24-49F9-9963-385D6E2AB049-608-000036FC1493AB36

The code make attribute read-only and after making price read only, it have disable the category function too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ->Display setting and uncheck box 'Available Product Listing sory by' and 'Default product listing sort by'. Me working fine. [image]